# Mean Stack: Change body background color on a certain view

Tags: html, css, angularjs, mean-stack

I am using the MEAN stack. When I am on a certain view, I was wondering if i can change the background color on the page. For example, if I click to go to the Contact view, I want the background color to change to blue for that view. I tried this on one of my views

```
<section ng-controller="HomeController" style="background-color #97D2D8;">

</section>
```

but it only changed the color of other items and not the page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngClass` or `ng-style`

**ng-style:**
in your controller declare a varaiable

```
myStyle={background-color:'red'}; //You can change the color according to the active view
```

Then in your view

```
<section ng-controller="HomeController" ng-style="myStyle">
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will works, You have missed `:` on your code, Here is the modified code below,

```
<section ng-controller="HomeController" style="background-color : #97D2D8;">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have missed ":" while putting the in-line style.
Correct way should be:

```
style="background-color: #97D2D8;"
```

Also you can also use ngClass directive which is provided by Angular to conditionally applied css over the DOM element.

Syntax:

Example:

```
<style>
.sky {
    color:white;
    background-color:lightblue;
    padding:20px;
    font-family:"Courier New";
}
.tomato {
    background-color:coral;
    padding:40px;
    font-family:Verdana;
}
</style>
<body ng-app="">

<p>Choose a class:</p>

<select ng-model="home">
<option value="sky">Sky</option>
<option value="tomato">Tomato</option>
</select>

<div ng-class="home">
  <h1>Welcome Home!</h1>
  <p>I like it!</p>
</div>
```

And also as per the best practices of writing CSS, do not write in-line styles instead make external style so that that class can be used across all the pages.

Example:

```
common.css
-----------
.back-color {
  background-color:#97D2D8;
}

index.html
----------
<section ng-controller="HomeController" style="back-color">

</section>
```